# Why multer should upload files before any operation?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

They way Multer works on top of express is wired!, why Multer should precede the controller in the chain of Middlewares, which which by design causes the server to upload stuff before the DB operation is even checked?

For instance if there was a post operation to articles, and it contains a bunch of fields one of them is a file.

```
articleModel{title:String,image:String};
router.post('/', multer, articleController.createArticle);
```

now at the time the request hits, first thing in the chain is to upload the file in the request, but what if an error happened at the execution of the record to the DB like validation or even duplicates, what if I am going to update the article title only? the old files will be uploaded again?

How to make multer upload the files in the response of the http operation callback?

Comment: Couldn't you just add a preceding middleware that does DB stuff before the multer middleware?  You can have multiple middlewares.

Comment: No, since the file path in the req.files will be undefined if the multer middleware is executed later so i cant

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed make all kind of stuff before Multer actually process the image:

```
var upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads/',
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    // only images are allowed
    var filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/;
    var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());

    if (mimetype && extname) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    cb("Error");
  }
}).single('localImg');

app.post('/api/file', checkBody, auth, uploadFile, controller.aController);
```

Take this code for example, you can make all kind of middleware actions BEFORE multer process your file, but multer is a library to process **multipart/form-data**, not files only, people use multipart for sending files mainly but you can send all kind of data too and it will append them to the body (req.body)

Your question is: "Why multer should upload files before any operation?"
You can execute multer when ever you want, but multer will process the request and get your data into the body. Unless you don't need the body data first hand, you need multer to be in the first middleware.

Your other question is: "what if I am going to update the article title only? the old files will be uploaded again?"

No, it will be uploaded once, if there is any problem with the database, any error or reject, you can always use the filesystem (fs) to remove the file from your server, if you already upload it to a third party system, you can delete it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, its the uploader and the body field handler at the same time, no exit